# Kotlin extension property is recognized in some app modules and not others

Tags: android, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm doing an application extension for my modularized android app (it has 4 modules).  I'm using the following utility code to initialize Application extensions:

```
class ApplicationLazy<out T>(private val initializer: Application.() -> T) : ReadOnlyProperty<Application, T> {
   private var value: T? = null

   override fun getValue(thisRef: Application, property: KProperty<*>): T =
     (value ?: initializer(thisRef).also {
      value = it
   })
 }

 fun <T : Any> appLazy(initializer: Application.() -> T) = ApplicationLazy(initializer)
```

And in one module (call it core), I'm defining database as such:

```
val Application.db by appLazy {
   Database(
     AndroidSqliteDriver(Database.Schema, this, "luminary.db"),
     HomeItemDto.Adapter(SectionIdColumnAdapter, EnumColumnAdapter(), EnumColumnAdapter()),
     HomeSectionDto.Adapter(SectionIdColumnAdapter, EnumColumnAdapter()),
     MediaItem.Adapter(MediaIdColumnAdapter, LocalDateTimeColumnAdapter, LocalDateTimeColumnAdapter)
   )
}
```

I can "see" that from anywhere in my four modules, not just the "core" module.  (Doing an Application.db) shows up in my list of choices in Android studio.  However, in a different module (call it audioplayer)  I'm defining an Exoplayer DataManager as such:

```
val Application.downloadManager: DownloadManager by appLazy {
  val downloadIndex = DefaultDownloadIndex(databaseProvider)
  upgradeActionFile(DOWNLOAD_ACTION_FILE, downloadIndex, false)
  upgradeActionFile(DOWNLOAD_TRACKER_ACTION_FILE, downloadIndex, true)
  val downloaderConstructorHelper = DownloaderConstructorHelper(downloadCache, dataSource(this, 
  SwaggerApiClient.userAgent))
  DownloadManager(this, downloadIndex, DefaultDownloaderFactory(downloaderConstructorHelper)).apply {
    requirements = Requirements(Requirements.NETWORK_UNMETERED)
  }
}
```

Calling application.downloadManager in another module when I compile, the compiler complains and says it is an unresolved reference. Why is this working when defined in one module and not the other?

**EDIT**
Here are the dependencies for the module that is calling this extension.

```
dependencies { //core
api project(":network")
}

dependencies { //app
}

dependencies { //network
}

dependencies { //audioplayer
  implementation project(':core')
}
```

Comment: Can you post the dependencies of one of the modules depending from `:audioplayer`?

Comment: @GiorgioAntonioli not sure what you mean.

Comment: You said  "Calling application.downloadManager in another module when I compile [...]", can you post the `build.gradle` of the module in which you'd like to use `application.downloadManager`?

Comment: @GiorgioAntonioli added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the module containing the extension as a dependency of the module which wants to use it.

So, imagining the extension `application.downloadManager` is in the module `:audioplayer`, you should add the dependency with `:audioplayer` in the modules which need that extension.

**e.g.**

```
dependencies {
    // Or "api project" if you want to make that extension accessible from the modules which depend from this module.
    implementation project(":audioplayer")
    ...
}
```

Comment: I get a circular dependency when trying to build.

Comment: @Kristy Welsh Does `:audioplayer` depends on the module you have posted?

Comment: No, it doesn't depend on it.  It's the other way round.

Comment: @Kristy Welsh I guess you should post all the 4 `build.gradle` files (the `dependencies` block of them). You can just post only the `project` dependencies. You can avoid to post the remote ones.

Comment: Posted them.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: BTW, I can see the extension value in the module "app"

Comment: Now it's everything clearer. Yours is a module-design problem. Imagine this scenario: if you have a module A which depends on the module B, it means that the module B can't see what's defined in the module A, otherwise you would have a circular dependency. To solve your problem the only way is to put that extension in the module B so both A and B can access it or make both A and B depending from C in which you can add that extension.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll try that.  You are a life saver.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210698/discussion-between-giorgio-antonioli-and-kristy-welsh).